# How to convert hex string to byte array in CAPL?

Tags: type-conversion, capl, canoe

Considering having, for example, this type of hex string:

```
char hex_str[100] = "0x01 0x03 0x04 0x0A";
```

How to get out of this string the byte array representation in CAPL, like:

```
byte hex_str_as_byte_arr[4] = {0x01, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0A};
```

EDIT: Only Vector CANoe supported data types/functions are allowed!

Comment: [`man sscanf`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sscanf/)

Comment: Added Canoe and Capl tag. Also edited my question to CAPL language.

Comment: Hmmm, taken the `','` out negates one of the answers.  Moving targets are hard to up-vote.

Comment: Yeah, but now.. the question will stay as it is. Because I'm not restricted how the string will be provided.. It's fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all...
Actually I've found a solution myself:

```
  char hex_str[100] = "0x01 0x03 0x04 0x0A";
  long data[4];
  dword pos = 0;

  pos = strtol(hex_str, pos, data[0]);
  pos = strtol(hex_str, pos, data[1]);
  pos = strtol(hex_str, pos, data[2]);
  pos = strtol(hex_str, pos, data[3]);

  write("0x%02x,0x%02x,0x%02x, 0x%02x", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
```

Now it's a simple cast: `(byte) data[0]`

Comment: The syntax in CAPL for strtol is: int strtol(char s[], dword startIndex, long& result);
 or int strtol(char s[], long& result);

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtok` to split the character array into separate hex strings, then use `long strtol( const char *restrict str, char **restrict str_end, int base )` to convert each hex string to an integral value.

Comment: Unfortunately strtok is not a Vector CANoe suppported function.

Comment: `strtok()` is a Standard C library function.  If your platform doesn't provide it, then it's not [tag:c].

Comment: Well, CAPL is actually based on C, but it doesn't support pointer and not all methods from the standard c lib.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sscanf()` to convert the numbers to `unsigned char`.  In a loop, we'll need to also use a `%n` conversion to determine the reading position for the next iteration.

Here's a simple example (in real life, you'll need some range checking to make sure you don't overrun the output buffer):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char hex_str[100] = "0x01, 0x03, 0x04, 0x0A";
    unsigned char bytes[4];

    {
        int position;
        unsigned char *b = bytes;

        for (const char *input = hex_str;  sscanf(input, "%hhi, %n", b, &position) == 1;  ++b) {
            input += position;
        }
    }

    /* prove we did it */
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < sizeof bytes;  ++i) {
        printf("%hhu ", bytes[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: `sscanf(input, "%hhi, %n", b, &position) == 1; ...     input += position;` is dangerous as it is not certain `position` has been set.  It is not known scanning went past the `','`.   The last `input += position;` will be UB.

Comment: Yes, good point.  On most platforms, it's safe to perform the addition if you don't dereference it, but that's not a portable assumption, so it should be fixed (e.g. by scanning the `,` into a dummy `char`, and testing for the return being 2 rather than 1).